# Replacing Vowels and Consonants Using List Comprehension Python

Tags: python, string, list, replace, list-comprehension

I'm trying to replace all of the letters in each element of a list of strings into either "C" for consonant or "V" for vowel. For example, if I were to have ["the", "cat"], I would want it to return ["CCV", "CVC"].

Is there a way for me to do this using list comprehension? If so, how?

Comment: Hi Ben, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack is a community where we ask/answer specific questions, in order to post a question you need to make previous research by yourself, show some code and share any error or unexpected behaviour you are finding. Please refer to [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), this guidelines will help you to improve your question. Thanks!

Comment: list(map(lambda x:''.join(map(lambda y:'V' if y in 'aeiouAEIOU' else 'C' ,x)), lis))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
new_list = [''.join(('V' if char in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'} else 'C') for char in string) for string in previous_list]
```